# Error 415 cannot send json to wcf service

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf

I have a problem - I need to send json over POST but my error is "error (415) cannot process the message because the content type application/xml", obviously there is some mismatch but I cannot find it. Here is my Web.config

```
    <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="23:59:59" openTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59" sendTimeout="23:59:59" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceContracts.Implementation.CR.CRService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding" contract="ServiceContracts.CR.ICRService" />
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceContracts.CR.ICRService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" address="rest" />
      </service>
      <service name="ServiceContracts.Implementation.SP1.SPOneService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding" contract="ServiceContracts.SP1.ISPOneService" />
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceContracts.SP1.ISPOneService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" address="rest"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
  </system.web>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get a proxy reader to see what you are actually sending, I suggest: [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).  Then you can match that up with what is expected.

I suggest also [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/) for your web-service, they provide excellent handling of object sending/receiving.  But if your too far along, you can still use ServiceStack's excellent object to JSON converters.  The neat thing about ServiceStack is that there are no config files.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with the *PUT* Http Verb - solution was to add the following Request Headers:

> **Accept: application/json
>
>   Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8**